# Calling protected variables in a class in another script

Tags: php, pdo

Am new to PDO, I have constructed the class as shown below. At Some point, I want to use the private variables in another script which requires this dbconnection.php

dbconnection.php

```
<?php
 class DBconnect
{
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'db_user';
    private $password = 'pass';
    private $dbname = 'db';
    

    protected function connect()
    {
        $config = 'mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbname;
        $pdo = new PDO($config, $this->username, $this->password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $pdo;
    }
}
```

user.php

```
<?php
require dbconnection.php
//how can I call the private variables here?
```

Comment: You can't use private properties from outside the class. Protected properties can only be used from subclasses.

Comment: Why did you make `connect` protected if you want to use it from outside the class?

Comment: Why do you need to access the private variables? The whole point of this class is that it hides the connection information from the caller.

Comment: @Barmar does it mean that I should change it to Public Function?

Comment: Yes, if you want to be able to call it. That's the whole point.

Comment: Why do you need such a class at all? Are you going to add more methods to it? If yes, then why do you return the PDO instance? This class makes no sense. I would just remove it.